# How do I Install Ubuntu on an iMac running OS X Lion on a SSD and Windows 7 on a HDD?

Tags: dual-boot

How do I Install Ubuntu on an iMac running OS X Lion on a SSD and Windows 7 on a HDD? I once successfully triple booted when I ran Snow Leopard, Windows 7, and Ubuntu. Now how can it be done with my more complicated and less forgiving lion set up?